# sql auto generated id when importing from file

Tags: postgresql, csv, import

I want to import some data into the Postgres database from local CSV file. My SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE trajectory (
  id          serial,
  lat         varchar(40),
  lon         varchar(40),
);
```

The CSV file looks as follows:

```
28.218273, 21.12938
...
```

And my import clause:

```
COPY trajectory FROM 'my directory\20081023025304.plt' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

But this gives an error:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "39.984702"
SQL state: 22P02
Context: COPY trajectory, line 1, column id: "39.984702"
```

The main problem is that I definitely need ID column in DB, but CSV file does not contain it. How can I add autogenerated id when importing the data (I mean ID=1 for first row, ID=2 for second, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define columns - [here is DOC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html):

```
copy trajectory (lat, lon) from my directory\20081023025304.plt delimiter ',' csv;
```